# UITableViewDelegate doesn't work with UITableViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uitableviewdiffabledatasource

I created test project to reproduce the issue https://github.com/msnazarow/DiffarableTest

Simply you need to pass several steps

1. Create new target
2. Create `Base` class that inherit `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` and also `UITableViewDelegate` but do not implement `UITableViewDelegate` methods
3. In another target(main for simplify) inherit `Base` class and implement any of `UITableViewDelegate` method (for example `didSelectRowAt`)
4. None of implementing methods would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the delegate funcs in your `BaseDataSource` class to be overridden in subclasses.

So, first step, comment-out your `didSelectRowAt` func in `extension MyDataSource`:

```
extension MyDataSource {
//  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//      print("CELL SELECTED")
//  }
}
```

and implement `didSelectRowAt` in `BaseDataSource`:

```
open class BaseDataSource<T: Model & Hashable>: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, T>, UITableViewDelegate {
    public init(tableView: UITableView) {
        super.init(tableView: tableView) { tableView, indexPath, model in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! Configurable
            cell.configure(with: model)
            return cell as? UITableViewCell
        }
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Base Cell Selected", indexPath)
    }
}
```

When you run the app and tap on the 3rd row, you should get debug output:

```
Base Cell Selected [0, 2]
```

To implement that in your subclass, you can override it:

```
extension MyDataSource {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("MyDataSource Cell Selected", indexPath)
    }
}
```

You'll get an error: *Cannot override a non-dynamic class declaration from an extension* ... so make it dynamic in `BaseDataSource`:

```
open class BaseDataSource<T: Model & Hashable>: UITableViewDiffableDataSource<Int, T>, UITableViewDelegate {
    public init(tableView: UITableView) {
        super.init(tableView: tableView) { tableView, indexPath, model in
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! Configurable
            cell.configure(with: model)
            return cell as? UITableViewCell
        }
    }
    public dynamic func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Base Cell Selected", indexPath)
    }
}
```

Tapping on the 3rd row now should output:

```
MyDataSource Cell Selected [0, 2]
```

Note that `didSelectRowAt` in `BaseDataSource` will be called if there is no sub-classed delegate. Plus, if you want some code to ***also*** run in `didSelectRowAt` in `BaseDataSource`, you can call `super` from the subclass:

```
extension MyDataSource {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        super.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        print("MyDataSource Cell Selected", indexPath)
    }
}
```

and selecting the 3rd row outputs:

```
Base Cell Selected [0, 2]
MyDataSource Cell Selected [0, 2]
```

---

**Edit**

After a little more research, this is considered by some to be a "bug" as it seems to have changed between Swift versions.

However, one big change along the way is that Swift originally did, but no longer, ***infers `@objc`***. Everyone ran into that when it became necessary to add `@objc` to funcs such as when used in selectors.

So, two ways to handle this...

First, as shown above, implement "do nothing" funcs for any table view delegate funcs you want to override in your subclass.

The second option, which sounds like you would prefer, is to declare the `@objc` method inside your subclass (or its extension):

```
extension MyDataSource {
    // add this line
    @objc (tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("MyDataSource extension Cell Selected", indexPath)
    }
}
```

Now you can go back to your original code, and you only need to add that one line to get the functionality needed.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
But i do not want to implement all delegate functions in BaseDataSource to be overridden in MyDataSource

Comment: @МихаилНазаров - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: But i do not get this behavior when i inherit NSObject.
Only with UITableViewDiffableDataSource

Comment: @МихаилНазаров - as I said, *After a little more research, this is considered by some to be a "bug"* ... so, if it ***IS*** a bug, declaring the `@objc` method "fixes" it. If it's ***NOT*** a bug, but rather a design implementation, then declaring the `@objc` method is "required."