# Delegate methods in child class not called when using generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a very similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393027/delegate-methods-in-child-class-sometimes-not-called-with-swift-5-compiler) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645685/protocol-methods-in-a-class-extension-are-not-called-under-specific-conditions) question and I think they might be related. The difference is that the delegate is not called when a generic view model is used.

In the first example below everything works as expected. Initialize a `ViewController`, which is a subclass of `SimpleListViewController`. When the cell is selected it prints "Here" because the superclass (`SimpleListViewController`) conforms to `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

```swift
class SimpleListVCModel {
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, String>! = nil
    var items = Array(0..<10).map{"This is item \($0)"}

    enum Section: String {
        case main
    }
    
    func configureDataSource(using collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
            var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            content.text = "\(item)"
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, String>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, identifier: String) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: identifier)
        }
    }
    
    func applySnapshot() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, String>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.main])
        snapshot.appendItems(items)
        
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}
```

```swift
class ViewController: SimpleListViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "List"
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        configureHierarchy()
        model.configureDataSource(using: collectionView)
        model.applySnapshot()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Here")
    }
}
```

```swift
class SimpleListViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    let model = SimpleListVCModel()
    
    func configureHierarchy() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: .init(appearance: .insetGrouped))
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
}
```

Now If I introduce generics, the collectionView delegate function is never called.

First create a subclass of `SimpleListVCModel` specifically for the `ViewController`.

```swift
class ViewControllerViewModel: SimpleListVCModel {
    func foo(){
        print("Foo")
    }
}
```

Then slightly modify `SimpleListViewController` to use a generic `SimpleListVCModel`.

```swift
class SimpleListViewController<M: SimpleListVCModel>: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    let model: M
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil

    
    //MARK: - Initializer
    init(model: M) {
        self.model = model
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Views
    func configureHierarchy() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: .init(appearance: .insetGrouped))
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
}
```

Finally modify `ViewController` to use a generic version of the `SimpleListVCModel`.

```swift
class ViewController: SimpleListViewController<ViewControllerViewModel> {
    override init(model: ViewControllerViewModel = ViewControllerViewModel()) {
        super.init(model: model)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "List"
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        configureHierarchy()
        model.configureDataSource(using: collectionView)
        model.applySnapshot()
        model.foo()
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Here")
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72721867/6257435

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be similar to the case in the answer I linked to in comments, but since it's a little different I'll post this answer here.

First, in your `SimpleListViewController`, implement `didSelectItemAt`:

```
class SimpleListViewController<M: SimpleListVCModel>: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    let model: M
    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    
    
    //MARK: - Initializer
    init(model: M) {
        self.model = model
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Views
    func configureHierarchy() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: .init(appearance: .insetGrouped))
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        collectionView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected item: \(indexPath) in SimpleListViewController")
    }

}
```

When you do that, you'll see an error in `ViewController`:

```
Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword
```

For the moment, comment out your `didSelectItemAt` func in `ViewController`.

Now, when you select an item, `didSelectItemAt` in `SimpleListViewController` will be called and it will print to the debug console.

Next, un-comment `didSelectItemAt` in `ViewController` and add the `override` keyword:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Selected item: \(indexPath) in ViewController")
}
```

Running the app now and selecting an item will call *that* func and print to the debug console.

Note that you can also call `super` ... so, if you have some default code you want executed in `SimpleListViewController`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Selected item: \(indexPath) in SimpleListViewController")
    // do something common
}
```

and in `ViewController`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    super.collectionView(collectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
    print("Selected item: \(indexPath) in ViewController")
}
```

and you'll get both `print` statements in the debug console.

If you'd rather *not* do it that way, you can remove the implementation from `SimpleListViewController` and instead declare the `@objc` method signature in `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: SimpleListViewController<ViewControllerViewModel> {
    override init(model: ViewControllerViewModel = ViewControllerViewModel()) {
        super.init(model: model)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "List"
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        configureHierarchy()
        model.configureDataSource(using: collectionView)
        model.applySnapshot()
        model.foo()
    }
    
    @objc (collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected item: \(indexPath) in ViewController")
    }

}
```

Note that you can no longer call `super` with that approach.